# Implement C# interface function returning array, in C++/CLI

Tags: c#, c++, c++-cli

I have a C++/CLI project that references a C# dll, and I need to implement an Interface class.

The interface class in C# looks like this:

```
public interface IMeshData{
    //(...)        
    INode NodeById(int nodeId);
    double[] NodeXYZById(int nodeId);
}
```

In the C++ project I can implement this interface:

```
public ref class IMeshData_class : public IMeshData{

public:
    //this one is accepted:
    virtual INode^ NodeById(int nid){
        return this->NodeById(nid);
    }
    //this one gives me an error:
    virtual double*  NodeXYZById(int nid){
         return this->NodeXYZById(nid);
    }
}
```

When I first define my class above without any member function, I get the error:

> Error: class fails to implement interface member function "IMeshData::NodeById" (declared in (...).dll)

So after defining the function `NodeById`, this error goes away, and I get:

> Error: class fails to implement interface member function "IMeshData::NodeXYZById" (declared in (...).dll)

`NodeXYZById` return a `double[]`, I thought this would *translate* to a `double*` in C++, but it doesn't seem to be the case.

How should I correctly implement a C# member function in C++ which returns an array?

Comment: My C++/CLI is **very** rusty, but I think there was an `array<double>^` for exactly that.

Comment: @TanveerBadar Great, that worked perfectly it seems, thanks. (If you make an answer, I'll accept it as a solution).

Comment: Posted as answer too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As commented above, in C++/CLI you have to use the type `array<T>^` in place of what might be `T[]` in C#.